# How can i enable auto play from this sitepoint bootstrap carousel tutorial?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i was thinking to use this in my project, but i couldn't enable the autoplay

http://codepen.io/SitePoint/pen/KwBWJd

i tried this way but didnt work.

```
$myCarousel.carousel({interval: 40000});
```

Thanks :)

Comment: From Stack Overflow docs: "Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**." Please copy the relevant code into your question - if you feel like it you could even create a [runnable Stack Snippet](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) of your code! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

comment out this line below and it will autoplay

`//$myCarousel.carousel('pause');`

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply  but there is another problem is, the interval settings is not working  , can you please help me so that i can set an interval for sliding ..
i tried this way but didn't work
 $myCarousel.carousel({
    interval:500
  });

Comment: fixed it, thank you again :)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to call the pause function like this: $myCarousel".carousel('pause');. This is how all methods are called on bootstrap components, following the jQuery UI convention.

Sir no Need to Use :`$myCarousel.carousel('pause');`
Working Fiddle :[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/XFcSv/)